# How do I recursively use Array.prototype.find() while returning a single object?

Tags: javascript, recursion

The bigger problem I am trying to solve is, given this data:

```
var data = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4, children: [
        { id: 6 },
        { id: 7, children: [
            {id: 8 },
            {id: 9 }
        ]}
    ]},
    { id: 5 }
]
```

I want to make a function `findById(data, id)` that returns `{ id: id }`. For example, `findById(data, 8)` should return `{ id: 8 }`, and `findById(data, 4)` should return `{ id: 4, children: [...] }`.

To implement this, I used `Array.prototype.find` recursively, but ran into trouble when the `return` keeps mashing the objects together. My implementation returns the *path* to the specific object.

For example, when I used `findById(data, 8)`, it returns the *path* to `{ id: 8 }`:

```
 { id: 4, children: [ { id: 6 }, { id: 7, children: [ { id: 8}, { id: 9] } ] }
```

Instead I would like it to simply return

```
{ id: 8 }
```

---

#### Implementation (Node.js v4.0.0)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2k5vpqn/)

```
var data = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4, children: [
        { id: 6 },
        { id: 7, children: [
            {id: 8 },
            {id: 9 }
        ]}
    ]},
    { id: 5 }
]

function findById(arr, id) {
    return arr.find(a => {
        if (a.children && a.children.length > 0) {
            return a.id === id ? true : findById(a.children, id)
        } else {
            return a.id === id
        }
    })
    return a
}

console.log(findById(data, 8)) // Should return { id: 8 }

// Instead it returns the "path" block: (to reach 8, you go 4->7->8)
//
// { id: 4,
//   children: [ { id: 6 }, { id: 7, children: [ {id: 8}, {id: 9] } ] }
```

Comment: WHY DID YOU ACCEPT WRONG ANSWER. FIX IT PLEASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a regular loop and recursive style search:

```
function findById(data, id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id === id) {
            return data[i];
        } else if (data[i].children && data[i].children.length && typeof data[i].children === "object") {
            findById(data[i].children, id);
        }
    }
}

//findById(data, 4) => Object {id: 4, children: Array[2]}
//findById(data, 8) => Object {id: 8}
```

Comment: I've been working through this and found that it short circuits. For example, when doing `findById(data, 5)`, it stops looking after it finishes searching the children of `id: 4`. It returns `undefined` when `i =3` which stops the function, and so never reaches `i=4`.

Comment: @KeithYong - Edited and fixed - removed the `return` before the recursion call.

Comment: the removal of the return makes it not return on the parent recursive call, so `findById(data, 6)` isn't working in the edited, could you check it out?

Comment: Why this has been chosen as the right answer? Have you tried findById(data, 9) or findById(data, 6)? Neither of them is correct.

Comment: This is not working. It shouldn't be marked as right answer

Comment: I modified the else if to be this  
`const result = findById(data[i].children, id);`
`if (result === undefined) continue;`
`return result;`

seems to have fixed it since the recursion was stopping when the children are empty. I'm sure someone could write it more elegantly

Answer (score 35):

The problem what you have, is the bubbling of the find. If the id is found inside the nested structure, the callback tries to returns the element, which is interpreted as true, the value for the find.

> The `find` method executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Description)]

Instead of find, I would suggest to use a recursive style for the search with a short circuit if found.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4, children: [{ id: 6 }, { id: 7, children: [{ id: 8 }, { id: 9 }] }] }, { id: 5 }];

function findById(data, id) {
    function iter(a) {
        if (a.id === id) {
            result = a;
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    }

    var result;
    data.some(iter);
    return result
}

console.log(findById(data, 8));
```

Comment: Could you please explain the 'some' property inside data? Updated: Nevermind

Comment: @faniva, it iterates the children by taking `iter` as callback with a short circuit, if the `id` is found.

Comment: Nina, I know its from a long time ago, but worth a try: what's the reason for using `some` over `find`? As `some` will still suffer from the same element return as `find` I realised I could use find and seems similar in logic to your approach. My answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66463532/339803

Comment: @redfox05, by using find, you are kind of cheating, because you do not use the returned result of `find`, but a side effect by getting an object as `find` or `undefined`. this is never used, because you still need an additional variable `result`. but even if not, you can not get another content using `find` because `find` returns either one of the element of the array (without the possibility of changing it) or `undefined`.

Answer (score 9):

Let's consider the implementation based on recursive calls:

```
function findById(tree, nodeId) {
  for (let node of tree) {
    if (node.id === nodeId) return node

    if (node.children) {
      let desiredNode = findById(node.children, nodeId)
      if (desiredNode) return desiredNode
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Usage

```
var data = [
  { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 },
  { id: 4, children: [
      { id: 6 },
      { id: 7,
        children: [
          { id: 8 }, 
          { id: 9 }
        ]}]},
  { id: 5 }
]

findById(data,  7 ) // {id: 7, children: [{id: 8}, {id: 9}]}
findById(data,  5 ) // {id: 5}
findById(data,  9 ) // {id: 9}
findById(data,  11) // false
```

To simplify the picture, imagine that:

- you are the monkey  sitting on the top of a palm tree;
- and searching for a ripe banana, going down the tree
- you are in the end and searches aren't satisfied  you;
- come back to the top of the tree and start again from the next branch;
- if you tried all bananas on the tree and no one is satisfied you, you just assert that ripe bananas don't grow on this this palm;
- but if the banana was found you come back to the top and get pleasure of eating it.

Now let's try apply it to our recursive algorithm:

1. Start iteration from the top nodes *(from the top of the tree)*;
2. Return the node if it was found in the iteration *(if a banana is ripe)*;
3. Go deep until item is found or there will be nothing to deep. Hold the result of searches to the variable *(hold the result of searches whether it is banana or just nothing and come back to the top)*;
4. Return the searches result variable if it contains the desired node *(eat the banana if it is your find, otherwise just remember  not to come back down by this branch)*;
5. Keep iteration if node wasn't found *(if banana wasn't found keep testing other branches)*;
6. Return false if after all iterations the desired node wasn't found *(assert that ripe bananas doesn't grow on this tree)*.

Keep learning recursion it seems not easy at the first time, but this technique allows you to solve daily issues in elegant way.

Comment: This is wrong... Because bananas does not grow on palm tree ! :D

Comment: i am getting undefined on node.children, even though the node has children, and I get return values if i address them by their names.
Can you tell me why is that?

Comment: @Purkhalo Alex is this a common pattern? Somehow i have never seen: `let desiredNode = findById(node.children, nodeId) if (desiredNode) return desiredNode`. It works beautifully just strange that no one mentions this when reading about recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but as another answer recently revived it, I'll another version into the mix.

I would separate out the tree traversal and testing from the actual predicate that we want to test with.  I believe that this makes for much cleaner code.

A `reduce`-based solution could look like this:

```js
const nestedFind = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (res, x) => res ? res : pred(x) ? x : nestedFind (pred) (x.children || []), 
    undefined
  )
 
const findById = (testId) => 
  nestedFind (({id}) => id == testId)


const data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, children: [{id: 6}, {id: 7, children: [{id: 8}, {id: 9}]}]}, {id: 5}]

console .log (findById (8) (data))
console .log (findById (4) (data))
console .log (findById (42) (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

There are ways we could replace that `reduce` with an iteration on our main list.  Something like this would do the same:

```js
const nestedFind = (pred) => ([x = undefined, ...xs]) =>
  x == undefined
    ? undefined
  : pred (x)
    ? x
  : nestedFind (pred) (x.children || []) || nestedFind (pred) (xs)
```

And we could make that tail-recursive without much effort.

While we could fold the two functions into one in either of these, and achieve shorter code, I think the flexibility offered by `nestedFind` will make other similar problems easier.  However, if you're interested, the first one might look like this:

```js
const findById = (id) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce (
    (res, x) => res ? res : x.id === id ? x : findById (id) (x.children || []), 
    undefined
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  {
    id: 4,
    children: [{ id: 6 }, { id: 7, children: [{ id: 8 }, { id: 9 }] }]
  },
  { id: 5 }
];

// use Array.flatMap() and Optional chaining to find children
// then Filter undefined results

const findById = (id) => (arr) => {
  if (!arr.length) return null;

  return (
    arr.find((obj) => obj.id === id) ||
    findById(id)(arr.flatMap((el) => el?.children).filter(Boolean))
  );
};

const findId = (id) => findById(id)(data);

console.log(findId(12)); /* null */
console.log(findId(8)); /* { id: 8 } */
```

Comment: Notice the infinite recursion when the value is not found.  Try finding id 12.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes, You are right, modified it to prevent infinite loop and return null if no result instead.  Thanks :)

Comment: Great.  Two further suggestions: (1) `.flatMap` is probably nicer than `.map` followed by `.flat`.  (2) [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1243641)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Purkhalo Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505965/1240074) solution,

I have made a modification to his function to be able to find the ID recursively based on a given dynamic property and returning whether the value you want to find or an array of indexes to recursively reach to the object or property afterwards.

This is like `find` and `findIndex` together through arrays of objects with nested arrays of objects in a given property.

```
findByIdRecursive(tree, nodeId, prop = '', byIndex = false, arr = []) {
    for (let [index, node] of tree.entries()) {
        if (node.id === nodeId) return byIndex ? [...arr, index] : node;

        if (prop.length && node[prop].length) {
            let found = this.findByIdRecursive(node[prop], nodeId, prop, byIndex, [
                ...arr,
                index
            ]);
            if (found) return found;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can control the property and the type of finding and get the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with reduce.

```
const foundItem = data.reduce(findById(8), null)
function findById (id) {
  const searchFunc = (found, item) => {
    const children = item.children || []
    return found || (item.id === id ? item : children.reduce(searchFunc, null))
  }
  return searchFunc
}
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to put that reduce inside the function.  You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61806253) for a similar approach that puts all this into a function.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* recursively use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in combination with [Array.prototype.flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const findById = (a, id, p = "children", u) => 
  a.length ? a.find(o => o.id === id) || findById(a.flatMap(o => o[p] || []), id) : u; 


const tree = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4, children:[{id: 6}, {id:7, children:[{id:8}, {id:9}]}]}, {id:5}];
console.log(findById(tree, 9));  // {id:9}
console.log(findById(tree, 10)); // undefined
```

Comment: Writing the code this way (as short as possible), in addition to making it unreadable, also encourages a developer not to go into how it works.
It works, but I don't like it.

Comment: @RomanovEugene excellent comment, thank you. Do you think an additional improvement using `function()` (instead of Arrow Function with explicit return) or without the pretty common `?:` (Ternary Operator) would help to make it more clearer for novice developers? I might add that too if necessary.

Comment: Can't edit you, so I created it as a new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67876302/11347983

Answer (score 0):

If one wanted to use `Array.prototype.find` this is the option I chose:

```
    findById( my_big_array, id ) {
        var result;

        function recursiveFind( haystack_array, needle_id ) {
            return haystack_array.find( element => {
                if ( !Array.isArray( element ) ) {
                    if( element.id === needle_id ) {
                        result = element;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    return recursiveFind( element, needle_id );
                }
            } );
        }
        recursiveFind( my_big_array, id );

        return result;
    }
```

You need the result variable, because without it, the function would return the top level element in the array that contains the result, instead of a reference to the deeply nested object containing the matching id, meaning you would need to then filter it out further.

Upon looking through the other answers, my approach seems very similar to [Nina Scholz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36915114/339803) but instead uses `find()` instead of `some()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you want to search recursively by id, it is better to use an algorithm like this one:

```js
function findById(data, id, prop = 'children', defaultValue = null) {
  for (const item of data) {
    if (item.id === id) {
      return item;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(item[prop]) && item[prop].length) {
      const element = this.findById(item[prop], id, prop, defaultValue);

      if (element) {
        return element;
      }
    }
  }

  return defaultValue;
}

findById(data, 2);
```

But I strongly suggest using a more flexible function, which can search by any key-value pair/pairs:

```js
function findRecursive(data, keyvalues, prop = 'children', defaultValue = null, _keys = null) {
  const keys = _keys || Object.keys(keyvalues);

  for (const item of data) {
    if (keys.every(key => item[key] === keyvalues[key])) {
      return item;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(item[prop]) && item[prop].length) {
      const element = this.findRecursive(item[prop], keyvalues, prop, defaultValue, keys);

      if (element) {
        return element;
      }
    }
  }

  return defaultValue;
}

findRecursive(data, {id: 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is not the shortest, but divides the problem into recursive iteration and finding an item in an iterable (not necessarily an array).

You could define two generic functions:

- `deepIterator`: a generator that traverses a forest in pre-order fashion
- `iFind`: a finder, like `Array#find`, but that works on an iterable

```js
function * deepIterator(iterable, children="children") {
    if (!iterable?.[Symbol.iterator]) return;
    for (let item of iterable) {
        yield item;
        yield * deepIterator(item?.[children], children);
    }
}

function iFind(iterator, callback, thisArg) {
    for (let item of iterator) if (callback.call(thisArg, item)) return item;
}
  
// Demo
var data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4, children: [{ id: 6 }, { id: 7, children: [{ id: 8 }, { id: 9 }] }] }, { id: 5 }];

console.log(iFind(deepIterator(data), ({id}) => id === 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function:

If it finds the item so the item returns. But if it doesn't find the item, tries to find the item in sublist.

**list**: the main/root list

**keyName**: the key that you need to find the result up to it for example 'id'

**keyValue**: the value that must be searched

**subListName**: the name of 'child' array

**callback**: your callback function which you want to execute when item is found

```js
function recursiveSearch(
      list,
      keyName = 'id',
      keyValue,
      subListName = 'children',
      callback
    ) {
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const x = list[i]
        if (x[keyName] === keyValue) {
          if (callback) {
            callback(list, keyName, keyValue, subListName, i)
          }
          return x
        }
        if (x[subListName] && x[subListName].length > 0) {
          const item = this.recursiveSearch(
            x[subListName],
            keyName,
            keyValue,
            subListName,
            callback
          )
          if (!item) continue
          return item
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

[Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64111322/11347983)'s solution, but more readable one:

```js
function findById(data, id, prop = 'children', defaultValue = null) {
  if (!data.length) {
    return defaultValue;
  }

  return (
    data.find(el => el.id === id) ||
    findById(
      data.flatMap(el => el[prop] || []),
      id
    )
  );
}
```